# What is meaning of symbol $\wedge$ in Probability with Martingales by Williams

Tags: measure-theory

On page 62 of probability with Martingales by Williams, he defines:

> For $n \in \mathbb{N}$, define
>   $X_n(\omega) := \{ |Y(\omega)| \wedge n\}^p$

I know $\wedge$ in the context of set theory, but that's it. What does it mean here?

I found these 2 uses:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wedge_sum

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wedge_product

But it isn't clear to me if they provide the solutions (I don't think so, one is for topological spaces, the other for vectors).

Thank you in advance.

Comment: It either means "max" or "min," but I can never remember which.

Comment: So, it either means $X_n(\omega) = \max[|Y(\omega)|, n]^p$, or $X_n(\omega) = \min[|Y(\omega)|, n]^p$. My guess is "min," if Williams is using some kind of truncation argument.

Comment: Here is a link that suggests it indeed means "min."  I have no idea why "min" points up and "max" points down.http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_mathematical_symbols

Comment: @Michael the upwards wedge is the (logical) intersection which naturally corresponds to min, whereas the downward wedge is the (logical) union which naturally corresponds to max.

Answer (score 2):

The answer is min, provided by [Michael](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/155065/michael) in the comments. Thank you, Michael!

Answer (score 0):

I think of it as generalizing the boolean operators, and v is a short for "vel" which means "or" in Latin.  (Not sure if that's the provenance of the symbol, but that's how I remember it...).  If you were implementing the boolean operators using min and max, you would use max or "or" and min for "and."